# DELETE after SELECT - will mysql maintain the same order?

Tags: mysql

I've got some existing code with couple of queries and I'm trying to figure out if the functionality is correct. The queries are performed on a simple table where integer unique IDs are stored.
So the code does the first query:

```
SELECT id FROM id_table LIMIT some_number;
```

then it does some operations on retrieved ids and removes them from the table:

```
DELETE FROM id_table LIMIT some_number;
```

From what I understand in mysql the order is not guaranteed (and no ORDER BY is specified in there). So will the second query delete the same records that were retrieved in the first query, given that nobody else does queries to id_table?

Thanks

Comment: when you have already selected the ids, why not delete based on the id? this approach looks buggy because data could have been inserted between the time select was run and when delete was run

Comment: This code assumes there's only one user on that table so nobody can insert or delete rows between those two queries. I was concerned however whether it relies on some mysql implementation detail that makes it delete same ids returned from SELECT. Because the code seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't do that. The fundamental problem is that unless you use an `order by` clause, there is no guarantee of the rows returned/deleted using `limit`.

You should use an `order by`, in both `select` and `delete`, on the same column(s), like this:

```
SELECT id from id_table order by id LIMIT some_number;

DELETE from id_table order by id LIMIT some_number;
```

You can order by anything you want as long as it's consistent, but `id` would be the logical choice for an auto_increment column.

Comment: Thanks! It is an existing code I'm trying to refine, it looks like it works somehow but it seemed wrong to me hence the question. I'll probably try to fix it by adding ORDER BY...

Comment: It will "work" without the order by, in the sense that it won't "error", but the effects would be indeterminant.